# Why call bool() directly?

Tags: python, boolean, truthiness

I've read that when python evaluates a conditional, that something like `if x:` would be translated to `if bool(x):`.  Why then do I see a lot of code that calls `bool()` directly?  Is this mostly for readability or is there some other advantage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bool()` in `if bool(x):` is *entirely redundant*. `if` will do the exact same thing *already*.

If you see code that does this (use `bool()` in a context where truth-testing already is taking place, such as an `if` or `while` statement), then there is *no advantage* whatsoever. In such contexts the [*truth value* of the object is tested](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), you don't need to convert it to a boolean first, that just creates double work.

Use `bool()` only when you need to explicitly convert to a boolean object; for example when storing the result in a variable or passing it to a function that needs to have a boolean value, or as if your function is documented as returning a boolean.

Comment: This is what I suspected.  But in what situation would it be advantageous to call `bool()` on a value instead of just returning the raw value and letting python call `bool()` when it's used in a conditional?

Comment: @JpajiRajnish: as stated in my answer: when an actual boolean object is required. If you are calling an API that is documented as taking a boolean object for an argument, or your function promises to return a boolean, but you have some different type of object instead.

Comment: @JpajiRajnish: say your function should return `True` or `False`, but you have instead produced a dictionary. If the algorithm of the function produced an empty dictionary that could mean you need to return `False`, or you need to return `True` if there is one key at least, then you could just use `return bool(dictionary)`, because an empty dictionary is considered false in a boolean context.

Comment: @JpajiRajnish: here is an example from the python stdlib: the `cgi` module has a `FieldStorage` class. It implements the `__nonzero__` method to signal it is 'true' or 'false' in a boolean context, and it can detect this from testing one attribute, so it returns `bool(self.list)`, see [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/cgi.py#l601).

Comment: @JpajiRajnish: another example, the `ctypes` package includes a `test` package, and the [`run_tests()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ctypes/test/__init__.py#l196) returns a boolean; if there were no errors, it returns `False`, otherwise it returns `True`; this is done by converting the `result.errors` list to a boolean (empty means `False`).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm getting at.  Why return `bool(self.list)` instead of just `self.list` when python is going to call `bool()` on any object in a conditional anyway?  It comes down to readability, right?

Comment: @JpajiRajnish: because you don't *know* if the caller is going to use the value in a Python test or perhaps store it in a file or send it to someone else in a JSON result.

Comment: @JpajiRajnish: If a function promises to return a boolean result, then you should really return a boolean and not something else.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks.